# Jestjs - FluentUI - suppress "The icon 'X' was used but not registered" warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, icons, fluent

I'm writing a react app that uses fluentUI.

while working on the system everything is fine (ofc I'm calling `initializeIcons()` function). however, when I'm running my test using jest, I keep getting the warning about 100 times, causing the output to be very messy and not understandable

how can i suppress the warning (even temporarily)?

Comment: Do you actually get the icons to show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to fluent documentation: (https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Using-icons#test-scenarios)

```js
import { setIconOptions } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Styling';

// Suppress icon warnings.
setIconOptions({
  disableWarnings: true
});
```